# Windows Automatic Updates on Windows VM in Azure Scale Set

Tags: azure, windows-update, azure-vm-scale-set

I have Azure Scale Set with a custom Windows VM image (syspreped Windows 2016 DC image with some app preinstalled).

There is an option to enable Windows automatic updates on the operating system, level, but I'm missing information how it affects the scale out scenario.

[image: Windows automatic update option]

For example I could have 3-months old VM image, not joined to any Active Directory domain. What is going to happen when new machines will be added to a scale set?

1. Windows updates are just enabled and machine is provisioned as is - updates will be installed later, some may require reboot.
2. Windows updates are installed during the VM provisioning - this may extend time adding the machine, but it will be 100% ready when provisioned.

Comment: You can also take a look at Azure Update Management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management#clients "Azure virtual machine scale sets can be managed through Update Management. Update Management works on the instances themselves and not on the base image. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Update will be enabled on the machine. The updates will be applied later and if required, reboot the new scaled out instances.

If desired, you may wish to deploy a startup script to apply all updates prior to your application starting up.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for the certain [platform provided images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade#supported-os-images). If you are using a custom image - this will not work.

If you are using one of the supported images - it will just create a VM using a newer base image and run extensions against that. you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade)

Comment: You are referring to the "Automatic OS image upgrade" options - which is totally right, but I was asking about the Windows automatic updates.